# sphere and inscribed cube

Tags: volume, fractions, ratio

We can express ratio between the volume of a cube and volume of inscribed sphere  in this cube as $6/\pi$ . What is the ratio between these objects  when the cube is inscribed in a sphere?

Comment: I would start with finding it in a 2nd-dimensional plane before putting it into the 3rd-dimensional cubes and spheres. So as in circles and squares

Comment: The largest cube that can be fit into a sphere will have its diagonal equal to the diameter of the sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the cube within the sphere. It has sides $s$ and long diagonal $2a$, where $a$ is the radius of the sphere. Applying the Pythagorean theorem twice, we can show that $s=2a/\sqrt{3}$. It then follows that

$$\frac{V_{sphere}}{V_{cube}}=\frac{\frac{4}{3}\pi a^3}{\frac{8a^3}{3\sqrt{3}}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{2}\approx 2.7207$$

Answer (score 0):

As the cube is inscribed, all its vertices will be touching the sphere. Thus, the largest diagonal of the cube will be equal to the diameter of the sphere.

If we let the edge length of the cube be $a$, then the largest diagonal of the cube will be equal to $a\sqrt3$ by the Pythagorean Theorem, and this will also be the diameter.

The volume of the cube will be $a^3$

From the formula for the volume of a sphere given the diameter ($\frac{1}{6}\pi d^3$), the area of the sphere is equal to $\frac{\pi}{6}\times (\frac{a\sqrt3}{2})^3=\frac{\pi a^3\sqrt3}{16}$.

Therefore, our ratio is $a^3/\frac{\pi a^3\sqrt3}{16}=\frac{16}{\pi\sqrt3}$

Comment: unfortunately(if i calculated correctly) 16/π√3=2.9404207755......  which is not correct , could you please  re-check your solution ?

Comment: @neo101 In the future, I'd put the answer in the question and a statement about how you know the answer but don't know the method, etc. this way people will know if their answer is right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

when the cube is inscribed in the sphere then all its vertices must lie on the sphere, therefore they are equidistant from the centre of the sphere. note that the centre of the cube(intersection of cube diagonals) is also equidistant from the vertices therefore centre of the cube and sphere match each other. therefore diagonal of the cube is the diameter of the sphere, then an easy Pythagorean theorem follows which connects the radius of the sphere and the side of the cube to each other.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I've calculated, sphere:incribed cube $= 2.7206990463:1.$
Since its about ratio, we can make the diameter of the sphere anything, so I took $2.$ This makes the space diagonal of the cube$=2.$ The sides of the cube are thus $2/\sqrt{3}.$ The volume of cube$= 8\sqrt{3}/9.$ The volume of the sphere is $4(\pi)r^3/3$ and in this case, $4(\pi)/3.$ If you take these two numbers $(4(\pi)/3$ and $8\sqrt{3}/9),$ the ratio of sphere to inscribed cube is $2.7206990463:1.$

Comment: yes , i did exactly the same as you did  . You putted  into fraction the whole calculations . But i am more interested in independent fraction from those calculations. Something like proposed Jazzachi in earlier answer .